# how to load spring without a web container

Tags: java, spring

I have a RESTful service using Jersey/Spring/Tomcat.  My question is - is it possible to access the classes within my war from command line (without the web interface)?

The problem is the JDBC connections and some other beans are managed by spring.  So how do I load all these beans without the web container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily initialize application context and load all the classes manually. Here is an example:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");
YourBean yourBean = applicationContext.getBean("yourBean", YourBean.class);        
applicationContext.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes in a WAR archive are tricky, because you'll have to tell the ClassLoader to look inside WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib/*.jar . Sounds non-trivial to me...

Comment: right, I've read that it is not the same to load a class from a war, as from a jar. Will try it.